# How to use Arquillian Graphene 2 with ChromeDriver

Tags: jboss-arquillian, arquillian-drone, graphene2

How do I use Graphene 2 with different browsers such as Chrome? (Default htmlUnit does not work well for me.)

Having Wildfly 8.1 server running inside Arquillian container, I'd like to use Drone + Graphene to execute actual tests.

```
@Drone
WebDriverdriver;

...

@RunAsClient
@Test
@InSequence(1)
public void basicHomepageTest() {

    // try to get the homepage
    driver.get("http://localhost:8080/superapp");

    // read title and source
    Assert.assertEquals("My Super App", driver.getTitle());

    // read content
    System.out.println("Page source -----");
    System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
}
```

I tried adding this to arquillian.xml config (with no luck):

```
<extension qualifier="webdriver">
    <property name="browser">chrome</property>
</extension>
```

Ending up with:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate Drone via org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver(Capabilities): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/se
    lenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleap
    is.com/index.html
```

Do I really need to embed Chrome binaries into my project somehow?

Comment: For more info on Arquillinan Graphene: http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-automation-using-arquillian-framework/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to embed it into your project per se, but the driver for Chrome is not shipped with the browser itself. You will have to download it and point Graphene to its location using `chromeDriverBinary` in your config file.

Answer (score 2):

Just to supplement bartozs's answer, here is what i did:

1) downloaded chromedriver binary for my OS [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

2) added path to binary to arquillian.xml

```
<extension qualifier="webdriver">
    <property name="browser">chrome</property>
    <property name="chromeDriverBinary">webdriver-bin/chrome/chromedriver.exe</property>
</extension>
```

Comment: You can also put it on your system/user environment path, so you won't have to hardcode a specific path.